# best refractory cement for embedded heating element furnace

Tags: heating-systems, electrical

first post

I designed a 2000 watts 1000 degrees Celsius furnace with following chamber size: 11 cm length, 12 cm width and 15 cm depth. The refractory that I use is 1880 C high temp tabular alumina refractory with 94 percent al2o3, 5 percent sio2, 0.2 percent fe2o3 and 0.6 percent cao. The heating element is 1.2mm in diameter with 2000 watts and is planted inside the refractory material with 3mm offset from inside of the chamber.

everything is OK so far but something is confusing me, here are the questions:

1- The furnace heat-rate is so slow (about 10 degrees in minutes). Is this problem is related to refractory?

2- What kind of refractory should I use for best performance and longer life cycle?

any kind of help would be very useful.

Comment: Any lab furnaces like this that I have seen used bare resistance wire on the surface of the refractory. The same for electric heat-treatment  furnaces. There is an thermal insulating affect when the wire is buried in the refractory.

Comment: @blacksmith37 yes it is, but As I know it is better to make the heating elements buried because of oxidation matters and avoid of electric shock by touching bare wires. like you said, heat trap is most common problem in this method actually.

Comment: Heating elements are normally Nichrome > Chromel > Inconel 600 or 601 ( essentially the same) ; excellent air oxidation resistance to 2200 + F.  One would need nearly a deliberate action to get shocked.